# Why returning a match from macro gives me type errors?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

Consider this example:

```
class A
object Macros {
  def genA(str: String): A[_] = macro _genA
  def _genA(c: Context)(str: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[A[_]] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr[A[_]](
      reify { new A[Int] }.tree)
}
// somewhere in code
genA("int") // --> new A[Int]
```

It works as expected. However, when I introduce a match, that selects an expression via match, I get into problems:

```
class A
object Macros {
  def genA(str: String): A[_] = macro _genA
  def _genA(c: Context)(str: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[A[_]] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr[A[_]](
      Match(
        str.tree.duplicate,
        List(
          CaseDef(Literal(Constant("int")), EmptyTree,
            reify { new A[Int] }.tree))))
  }
}
// again, somewhere far, far away in the code
genA("int") // it expands to ("int" match { case "int" => new A[Int] })
```

It compiles fine, but after macro expansion I get this error:

```
found   : rsf.macros.A[Int]
required: rsf.macros.A[_$1] where type _$1
       genA("int")
           ^
```

The same expression, when entered manually, compiles fine:

```
val a: A[_] = "int" match { case "int" => new A[Int] }
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I now use the following workaround:

```
class A
object Macros {
  def genA(str: String): A[_] = macro _genA
  def _genA(c: Context)(str: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[A[_]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val mtch = c.Expr[A[_]](
      Match(
        str.tree.duplicate,
        List(
          CaseDef(Literal(Constant("int")), EmptyTree,
            reify { new A[Int] }.tree))))
    reify {
      mtch.splice.asInstanceOf[A[_]]
    }
  }
}
```

But I feel that every time this macro executes, somewhere a kitten dies. Maybe there is some way to spare the kittens?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. Have you filed one?